# stop auto flush caches

Tags: 7, caching

I have Drupal 7 site.
somehow - every time I make any change in the site- the caches flushed (all the anonymous users can see the changes).

I want that the anonymous users will be able to see the changes only after flushing the caches manually (by clicking on the "Flush all caches" button in the Performance module).

I tried a lot of thing but with no success. for example:

- Use [CacheExclude](https://www.drupal.org/project/cacheexclude) module
- Disable it in [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module
- Use [Cleaner](https://www.drupal.org/project/cleaner) module (disable the option in settings)

here is my performance settings:

---

[image]

---

Please try to help me with that!

Comment: What do you mean by "any change in the site"? Configuration? Content?

Comment: In your screenshot, you need to checkmark Cache pages and Cache blocks.

Comment: @cilefen - changes in content

Comment: @NoSssweat - I tried it now with no success. still I can see changes in content right after also before flushing the caches.

Comment: @Chani maybe your CacheExclude module is excluding pages from being cached. (which is the opposite of what you're trying to accomplish)

Comment: @NoSssweat - that what I thought, so I removed the module from the site. and still have problems.